# Interior point V.S sqp algorithm for large scale optimization

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I have an large scale optimization problem that works with `fmincon` solver within `sqp` algorithm. But it is so slow. However, `Interior point` algorithm dis very fast but it doesnt find correct answers for this problem.

Is it mathematically possible to do some settings (initial points,...) in order to get solutions with `Interior point` as well?
In the literature of the problem, `Interior point` algorithm is suggested.

Comment: What kind of problem is that? Could you write it down to better understand? Most likely you can improve the model first. On the other hand, fmincon is designed to be fairly generi. Maybe you need a more specialized algorithm.

Comment: Its an optimization problem with 400 design variables. The objective function is linear, constraints are both linear and nonlinear -equality and inequality. These constraints have square and also sin(). @AC_MOSEK

Comment: So it is most likely a non convex problem. I would give a try to Ipopt https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/wiki, I am pretty sure it has a MATLAB interface.